# Does $a_n = n\sin n$ have a convergent subsequence?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I know that $\sin n$ has a convergent subsequence since it is bounded, but does the unbounded sequence $n\sin n$ have a convergent subsequence?

Given a subsequence of $\sin n$ that tends to zero, it is still possible that when we multiply the convergent subsequence $\sin(n_k)$ by $n_k$, the limit may not be $0$.

Comment: Compare: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/164390/does-leftn2-sin-n-right-have-a-convergent-subsequence/164402 (a more general question, despite the title)

Answer (score 8):

Yes.

Since $\pi$ is irrational, we have ***infinitely many*** rationals $p/q$ ([Dirichlet's approximation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_approximation_theorem)) such that
$$\left| \pi - \frac{p}{q} \right | < \frac{1}{q^2}$$
This implies $$|\sin p | = |\sin(q\pi - p) | < |q\pi - p| < \frac{1}{q} $$
Hence $|p\sin p| < \frac{p}{q}$, which is bounded.

Thus we have obtained a bounded subsequence of $\{n\sin n\}$, from which we can further select a convergent subsequence.

Comment: It seems like you are using some version of [Dirichlet's approximation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_approximation_theorem), which (at least to me) is a somewhat nontrivial result.

Comment: (+1) btw I don't think you actually require $\pi$ irrational

Comment: @Timkinsella   Could you elaborate what do you mean?

Comment: It seems true that for *all* $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ there are infinitely many $p,q\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $|\alpha - p/q|<1/q^2$. Anyway, its not so important.

Comment: @Timkinsella   I am sorry, my bad. $|\alpha - p/q|<1/q^2$ indeed also has infinitely many pairs satisfying it when $\alpha$ is rational. But this is not a crucial point.

Comment: @pisco yeah, I guess its just the totally trivial point that your proof also works for functions with rational period.

Comment: It impossible to apply the above solution to the sequence $n^2\sin n$ because of the index 2 in the Dirichlet theorem. What to do in that case?

Comment: @pabodu   Then this becomes an unsolved problem due to limited knowledge on irrational exponent of $\pi$, see the answer of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/164390 for details.